# Multipling two polynomials - Not exactly FFT

Tags: algorithm, fft

I'm currently studying FFT and I have trouble solving the following question:

Write a "divide and conquer" algorithm which multiplies two polynomials (max N degree) in complexity:

Theta of n^log3 (base 2 log ofc)

The algorithm should divide the two given polynomials coefficients into two groups:

Group1) Coefficients with even indexes.
Group2) Coefficients with odd indexes.

ehm, I don't even know how to start thinking about the solution.. 
The guidelines seem to be similar to FFT algorithm but I still can't see the solution.
Would love to get some assistance! even just a way to think about it..

please note that no code should be supplied.. only explanations and maybe pseudo code about how to get it done.

thanks !

Comment: Have a search for Karatsuba, e.g. [here](http://simomaths.wordpress.com/2012/10/08/polynomial-multiplication-karatsuba-and-fast-fourier-transform/)

Comment: It's been a long while since I've studied this sort of stuff, but here's a few ideas. One, the FT of a non-periodic function can be computed, usually involves the diract delta function. All polynomials are non-periodic. Two, the usual approach for these sort of problems is to transform the original function into Fourier-space, perform the multiplication there, and then perform the inverse FT to get back. Does that help? Here's wolfram alpha showing the FT of x^2: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier+transform+x%5E2

Comment: lovely! thanks peter.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few hints, then the solution.

**1 -** 
First of all, you should make sure that you can perform the multiplication in less than n^2 coefficient multiplications, on a simple example :

(aX + b)*(cX + d)

One of your multiplications should be (a+b)*(c+d)

**2 -** 
Haven't found how to do it ? 
Here are the operations for each power :

X^2 : ac

X   : (a+b)*(c+d) - ac - bd

1   : bd

You just have to perform 3 multiplications instead of 4. Additions do not cost that much compared to multiplications.

**3 -** 
You are asked to find a solution in Theta(n^lg(3)). Here is a quick reminder of the 'Théorème Général' :

Let T(n) the cost of your algorithme for the polynoms with degree n.

With a 'divide to conquer strategy' which leads to :

T(n) = aT(n/b)+f(n)

If f(n)~O(n^lg_b(a)) then T(n) = Theta(n^lg_b(a))

You are looking for T(n) = Theta(n^lg_2(3)). This could mean that :

T(n)=3.T(n/2) + epsilon

If you split your polynoms in even and odd polynoms, they have half of the initial coefficients amount : n/2.

The formula shows you that you will perform three multiplications between the odd and even polynoms...

**4 -** 
Consider to represent your polynom P(x) with degree n this way :

P(X) = X.A(X) + B(X)

A(X) and B(X) contain n/2 coefficients.

**5 - Solution**

P(X) = X.A(X) + B(X)

P'(X) = X.A'(X) + B'(X)

The coefficients of P*P'(X) is the sum of the coefficients of :

X^2.A.A'

X.(A.B'+A'.B) = X.[(A+B)(A'+B') - A.A' - B.B']

B.B'

So you have to call your multiplication algorithm on :

A and A'

A+B and A'+B'

B and B'

Then you can recombine coefficients with shifts and additions.

Cheers